# How to pause a song when another song starts?

Tags: windows-phone

I am developing windows phone app. I added list of 10 songs in it.
Problem:when I am playing 1st song an after some times if I starts 3 rd or any other song then how to pause the running song?

Comment: what apis are you using to play the song?

Comment: try to use XNA audio services.

Comment: Api as in?? I am not getting you

Comment: how to use XNA Can you please explain?

Comment: API as in, what kind of music player are you working with, where are songs to be played stored? Please elaborate your question

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203895(v=xnagamestudio.31).aspx

Comment: can u give code for ur listbox_selection changed event